# Segmentation fault _invalid memory reference

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, subroutine

I am very noob with fortran so your help is very useful to me! I had this problem when I execute my code. I saw the same problem in other questions but it wasn't useful to me. This is the problem that i receive:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7fedb8f212ed in ???
#1  0x7fedb8f20503 in ???
#2  0x7fedb8b53f1f in ???
#3  0x7fedb956e69f in ???
#4  0x55d432e60d0f in ???
#5  0x55d432e61488 in ???
#6  0x55d432e61a72 in ???
#7  0x55d432e60ade in ???
#8  0x7fedb8b36b96 in ???
#9  0x55d432e60b19 in ???
#10  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

The problem is related to the function agama_potforcederiv(c_object,xk,force,deriv) but i don't know why. xk is a 3 component and force and deriv are the outputs that I have to receive. This is the definition of a subroutine that needs my principal code to execute. I know that the problem is there because I received the text outputs before. I share some code to show better the problem. If I have to show more please tell to me. Thank you very much!

```
      SUBROUTINE USRFUN(XA,N,NP,FVEC,FJAC)
      INTEGER N,NP
      REAL*8 XA(N),FVEC(NP),FJAC(NP,NP),XK(3),TKK
c      REAL*8 PXE,PYE,PZE,PXXE,PYYE,PZZE,PXYE,PXZE,PYZE                                                                                                                                                     
      double precision force(3),deriv(6), pot1, agama_potforcederiv
      INCLUDE 'inc/patternspeed.f'
      INCLUDE 'inc/cpotential.f'

      write(*,*)'¿Que ocurre?'
      XK(1)=XA(1)
      XK(2)=XA(2)
      XK(3)=0.D0
      write(*,*)'¿Que ocurre?'
      pot1 =  agama_potforcederiv(c_object, xk, force, deriv)
      print*, 'Dfy/Dz', deriv(2)
      write(*,*)'si este mensaje sale soy feliz'
c      TKK=100.d0                                                                                                                                                                                          
c      CALL FISOBDEREF (TKK,XK(1),XK(2),XK(3),PXE,PYE,PZE,PXXE,PYYE,PZZE,                                                                                                                                  
c     &                 PXYE,PXZE,PYZE)                                                                                                                                                                    
      write(*,*)force(1),force(2)                                                                                                                                                                           
      FVEC(1)=force(1)-OMEGS2*XA(1)
      FVEC(2)=force(2)-OMEGS2*XA(2)
c      write(*,*)fvec(1),fvec(2)                                                                                                                                                                           
      FJAC(1,1)=deriv(1)-OMEGS2
      FJAC(1,2)=deriv(4)
      FJAC(2,1)=deriv(4)
      FJAC(2,2)=deriv(2)-OMEGS2

      RETURN
      END

``
```

Comment: Don't waste your time trying to debug Fortran code without the `implicit none` statement in each scope.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Your code is in a an old-style - very difficult to read and very incomplete. The lack of `IMPLICIT NONE` makes it very hard to keep track of the variables and enables very simple error. Your error output with the backtrace is useless. Always use `gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall` or `ifort -g -warn -check` or similar when debugging your code. Please try this and report back. More code will likely be necessary.